# Preventing Save througth conditional arguments without preventing Saveas due to the same conditions

Tags: excel, vba, save

I have a template I have been working on. The Sheet uses a two main functions I will be talking about. First is a Save(func) which saves a copy of the document to the correct folder while leaving the template be. The second is a Rev Up function, Whenever a change is made to the template a new copy is saved so the old one remains. Both of these functions work perfectly.

The issues comes from human error. When the template is open it is very easy to hit save(the in excel version not the VBA button I created) or to when closing the template the "file not saved" pops up and again it is easy to hit save.

When someone is working from there desktop they will often use a prefiled in spread sheet as some of them have a lot of overlap which can save a lot of work vs starting with the template. So all of my functions have to remain active. When working on a prefiled in sheet, both of those issues are magnified as they cause a lot of mistakes and lost work.

To solve this problem I have added 3 functions that all work fine on there own.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)


If Fileonly = Filename Then    

    Else:
        Cancel = True 'Cancels any request to save the file
        MsgBox "File name does not match part number, Use Rev up button for format changes or use Save button to create new file!"
End If
```

I want this code to active when the save button is hit. Then compare the current filename to the name that would be given to the file if the file was saved(func) right there. This code does exactly what i want it to do... and more.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
If ThisWorkbook.Saved = False Then

ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=*backupfilelocation*

End If
```

This code is used to supresse the "do you want to save changes" the file will set itself to saved then it will save a copy of the file to a back up location if you saved on accident. Again this code works perfect. But the `Saveas` function triggers the `beforesave` code. Then prevents the file from saving.

I have 2 other macros that also save the file. How do I allow the `saveas` to work while suppressing the ability to save over, unless the titles match.

Comment: is your document saved as an [`XLTX`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Save-a-workbook-as-a-template-58c6625a-2c0b-4446-9689-ad8baec39e1e)?

Comment: "preventing save but allowing save as" sounds very, very, very, VERY much like read-only, doesn't it?

Comment: My document is saved as a XLSM
As for making the document read only that would only solve some of my issues. The template would be safe, but working from your own desktop could still compromise other folders. And again Saving is ok if it passes the file name check. -I have updated the title to make this more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Workbook_BeforeClose Occurs before the workbook is saved, it doesn´t matter if it a "Save" or "Save as..." as describe [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.beforesave)

So this procedure will work always and just place a MsgBox to bet the value of ThisWorkbook.Saved to monitor it.

If you want to really "Save as..." as you will always trigger this procedure it is adding a "Save as..." after the backup saving.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
If ThisWorkbook.Saved = False Then
ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=*backupfilelocation*
End If
If ThisWorkbook.Saved = False Then ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs
```

So if you use "Save", will work as expected and if you used "Save as...", it will create a bckup file but it will allow you to save as properly.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Would the second If statement ever be true? The first if statement is identical and turns the second one to false.

Comment: If you are coming from Save it will be true si you won't get a save as windows. If you are coming from Save as, it will be false and you will get your desired Save as windows.